# Windows resource editor for Linux

Tags: windows, linux, command-line, resources, tcl

Is there any *command line* tool for Linux (FreeBSD, etc) which can modify like [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) versioninfo in exe file?

There are some utils for that purpose under Windows, but I'm doing cross-building of Windows Tcl Starpacks on FreeBSD.

Of cource it is possible to recompile TclKit with my versioninfo and icons but I don't want to do it for each different application--it seems that tweaking starpack's .exe afterward is a better solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run Resource Hacker under FreeBSD using [wine](http://wiki.freebsd.org/Wine) (it's marked as working in wines [AppDB](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=4047&iTestingId=37094)).

Comment: I hate wine--it almost every time crashes for me even with "supported" apps.

Comment: Does it crash with Resource Hacker? (You should try it before you apply your experiences with other apps to the one you want to use now.)

Comment: I have to acknowledge my defeat: it works as was supposed to. Except for always returning 0 even if modification of a resource failed.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't Resource Hacker work under [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/)?