# How can I modify an embedded resource on a PE File from a linux server?

Tags: linux, windows, portable-executable

Here's a simple example of what I'm looking for:

A PE file that uses a string table type resource. Say, the id/value of a string resource is as follows:

101 -> "Hello"

Now, on a linux server, I need to modify the PE file so that the value of Hello changes to "Hola", resulting in:

101 -> 'Hola', or may be

101 -> 'bonjour'

so, the new value may increase or decrease the size of the resource.

If you have done this, or know how to do this, I'll greatly appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412264/windows-resource-editor-for-linux? You can still use wine, it only gets better with time. :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'm not sure if I can introduce wine to the mix